# Counting paths of a certain length between a source and sink vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I have a graph $G$, which may be directed or not, and I was wondering if there was an efficient way of using, say, `BreadthFirstScan[]` and `FindShortestPath[]` to count the number of paths between some source vertex, $v(a)$, some sink vertex, $v(b)$, of a certain length $D$?

As of right now, I'm simply sequentially running through all of the vertices in my graph, applying `FindShortestPath[]` to determine the distance of the vertex to my source and sink vertices, and then seeing if the total distance is $D$.  If the total path distance is in fact $D$, I then put the path in a list which is later pruned for redundant paths or paths that revisit vertices.

Assuming I have plenty of memory to spare, is there a better / faster solution?

---

Let me better specify what I'm looking for -

Provided an undirected or directed graph $G$, I want to count the number of possible ordered sets, $(q_1,...,q_N)$, of all-unique vertices, $(v_{source}, ..., v_{sink}) \in q_i$, that one must visit to move from a source vertex, $v(source)$ to a sink vertex, $v(sink)$ s.t. $||q_i|| = D$ for all $q_i$, i.e. s.t. the total number of vertices along any path $q_i$ (including the source and sink) is $D$.  Two paths, $(q_a, q_b)$, may have common vertices, but individual $q_i$ cannot have redundant vertices (i.e. they are not multisets).

Please note, however, that I would be open to elegant/nice solutions that allow repeat vertex visits but forbid repeat edge traversals.

Comment: Read the answer off the $(a,b)$ entry in the $D$th power of the graph's adjacency matrix (using `MatrixPower`).

Comment: @whuber The usual "problem" with that is that it also counts paths with repeated vertices, e.g. `1->2->1->2` is a lengh 4 path between 1 and 2.  It's up to the OP to decide is this is a problem for his application.  Just something good to be aware of.

Comment: @whuber Right, that repeated vertex problem is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Peter It'd be good if you could update the problem with a precise formulation (explaining what you mean by path, and whether repeated vertices or repeated edges are allowed---two different things!)  The current solution you are currently using does neither and won't correctly count the number of paths.  To sum up: a precise formulation is needed.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wrote a hopefully more specific description...

Comment: Peter, are you really sure you meant to say you want to count *sets* of vertices and not the actual paths? The former, of course, ignores the sequence in which the vertices are visited.  There is a contradiction between what you say and the notation you use.

Comment: @whuber Yikes!  I specified that the sets should be ordered just now.

Comment: Using [FindPath](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath.html), you can list all path of length exactly $D$ between $s$ and $t$ (and then just count them).

Answer (score 4):

```
FindPath[G, 1, 2, {L}, All]
```

where $G$ is some graph. This finds all paths of length exactly $L$ edges  which run between nodes $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Well, that's just mrm's comment -- No test cases, no corner cases. Try to expand on it otherwise it's just the same thing.

Comment: this actually gives the command

Comment: And ? We do have the link to the whole documentation page just half a screen above

Comment: Some people want fast

Comment: Since this *is* an answer to the question, I think it should be written as an answer and not just a comment.  The comment was too easy to miss.  Generally, the existence of a comment that also answers the question shouldn't prevent anyone else from posting it as an actual answer.